# Is it possible to programmatically set the Safari Extension Whitelist?

Tags: safari, whitelist

I have successfully written my first Safari Extension. It loops through all input elements and removes "autocomplete" attributes from the type="text" elements. This overrides **idiotic** websites which turn off autocompletion (e.g. remembering usernames and passwords).

I define the Whitelist of my extensions (in the developers tools) to be the websites I want this to work on. A major disadvantage - which is stopping me from publicly releasing this extension - is that every time I want it to apply to a new website, I have to add it to the Whitelist in the development tools and reload the extension.

Is there a way to programmatically edit the Whitelist or expose it to the users (and not just the developers)?

Comment: I was looking into creating the exact same extension as you just described, but I have no experience with writing Safari Extensions... it's just a means to an end for me... would you mind sharing your extension with me?

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare sure no problem - I'll add it to github. Might be nice if you up-voted my question ;-) e-mail me at my username AT gmail.com to remind me.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare https://github.com/fommil/safari-always-autocomplete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that this is not possible. You will need to login to the Apple Developer Forums to read the discussion there:

https://devforums.apple.com/message/660858

which resulted in filing an RFE with Apple.